# Auto_increment column value required

Tags: mysql

Suppose i have table with column auto_increment and multiple inserts are going on concurrently:

```
INSERT INTO service_request.service_request_data(emp_id,sales_force_id,type_of_request,rfp_rfi,closure_deadline,mode_of_submission,submission_date,clarification_date,extention_date,region,item_status,participants_status,reviewer_status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And, i need auto increment id for my inserted data. How can i get that. May be after my insert many insert would have happenend.

Kindly, help me to find out this.

Comment: Are you using something like PDO?

Comment: PDO i didn't get sorry. Explain?

Comment: Is this what you mean : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html or do you want auto increment on a field other than the primary key

Comment: Out of curiosity, did my answer help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for that. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is the documentation.

That function works *per session* (in other words, *per connection*). If multiple `INSERT`s from different sessions (connections) are going on concurrently, each session (connection) will be returned the value it has inserted last, independently from other sessions (connections).

But please read the documentation thoroughly as that function behaves surprisingly in parts. For example, if the *same* session inserts *multiple* rows *at once*, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return the ID of the *first* row which has been inserted. So you eventually have to combine it with `ROW_COUNT()` to actually get the ID which the very last row inserted has generated.

Furthermore, you'll have to take into account how `LAST_INSERT_ID()` works in transactions, triggers and events, and what it does in case of transaction rollbacks or commits.

`ROW_COUNT()` can also be a complex beast with surprising behavior. For example, look what it does when used after an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. It is all in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) which you probably need to read multiple times to fully understand it (I had to).